# Search a String in text file in python

Tags: python

```
import os
import random
import sys

def search(a):
   datafile = open("test.txt","r")
   quote = datafile.read()
   quote_list = quote.split(" ")
   d = len(quote_list)
   print(quote_list)
   for x in range(0,4):
    string = quote_list.pop()
    print(string)
    if(string==a):
        return 0
    else:
        continue



print("Enter the word to search")
b = sys.stdin.readline()
c=search(b)
if(c==0):
  print("Found")
else:
  print("Not Found")
```

This code for searching a particular string in a text file is not working. Please help me to rectify the issue.

Comment: The part of the code which reads in the search value has the same indentation as the function body and thus is considered part of it. Unindent that part of the code and it will be executed upon execution of the script.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `print("Enter the word to search")  b = sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `b = raw_input("Enter the word to search")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
c=search(b)
```

to:

```
c=search(b.strip())
```

The newline in the user-input is probably what's getting in your way.

Other than that you probably want to change:

```
for x in range(0,4):
```

to:

```
for x in quote_list:
```

and get rid of the parameter `d`

Comment: Nope, the issue simply was indentation. Since you edited the question it became redundant because it actually works now.

Comment: @a_guest the OP disagrees with you ;) usually such indentation issues are due to copy & paste into the browser, and they're not the *real* issue.